# Started to learn UML and OCL and when to use Inv, pre, post

Tags: uml, ocl

So, I started learning OCL about 3 hours ago. I'm very confused about when you can use `inv` and when you need to use `pre` and `post`.
So I was wondering whether you can use `inv` in a situation like this?

```
context Service :: cost(d : double)
   inv result = workDone.cost -> sum()
```

this is in answer to a question:
Write an OCL invariant stating that the total cost for a service is the sum of the costs
for all the work done on the car you must assume the existence of a method
Service::cost() and specify the result.

As you can see its asking for the ocl invariant stating, does this mean I have to use `inv`?

cheers

Comment: I would stereotype the constraint with `<<invariant>>`. I still can't write OCL and since there is no real OCL compiler I guess there is no real need to follow up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think an invariant is the right thing to use. When the method first starts in some implementation language, before the sum has its final value, an invariant would be violated. Thus, I think you want a post condition. A post condition tells you what should be true when the method returns.

Comment: The whole OCL forms the constraint. And being inv, pre or post is the time when it applies. So although I'm not a OCL pro I would say your answer is not correct. According to what I read in http://st.inf.tu-dresden.de/files/general/OCLByExampleLecture.pdf the OP's form is correct.

Comment: Probably instead of `result` the constraint should be named `totalCostSum` or the like.

Comment: @ThomasKilian: even that lecture says, "An invariant is a constraint that should be true for an object during its complete lifetime." Before the method has completed, an invariant would be false. How is my answer incorrect?

Comment: As said: I'm not a OCL guru and I'm just speculating. But the task is to write an invariant which postulates the named condition. This is done with `inv <constraint> = <condition>`. I'm just unsure how to write `<condition>` and likely the above is wrong. But it's not about invariant/post.

Comment: Sometimes people are sloppy with wording.